# Shouldn't this question asking for books and learning resources be closed?

Tags: discussion

I recently came upon this question:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25860/is-there-a-pedagogical-game-engine

It appears to be a question where there is no single correct answer. It appears to be heavily related to the "how to get started" and "which tech to use" question sets. I just intuitively see it as a poll asking for resources such as many similar questions that have been closed previously.

If there is in fact something about it that makes it worthwhile for the site then I would like to learn from it so I could apply this to improve my questions.

Here are similar successful questions asking for resources that were closed:

[Game development Blogs](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/game-development-blogs)

[Where can I find free sprites and images?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20/where-can-i-find-free-sprites-and-images)

Basically I'm asking if the site rules where changed recently?

Answer (score 1):

I agree it should be closed, and have done that. In the future, you can simply vote to close yourself, or flag the question if it requires moderator attention. There's no need to open a meta question for each main site question you think should be closed.

The site rules have been changing since its creation. Sometimes questions aren't closed because they slipped through the cracks, sometimes they're not closed because they weren't considered off topic when they were asked.

Comment: I agree, I was mainly surprised by it.